# Thymeleaf construct object

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Im passing a model attribute from controller to thymeleaf form so I could bind object like this:

```
<div class="container" style="max-width: 600px" th:fragment="signupForm">
    <form name="f" th:action="@{/signup}" th:object="${userCredentials}" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
        <input th:placeholder="#{messages.form.email}" type="text" th:field="*{email}"
               name="email" id="email" class="form-control"/>
        <input th:placeholder="#{messages.form.name}" type="text" th:field="*{name}"
               name="name" id="name" class="form-control"/>
        <input type="password" th:placeholder="#{messages.form.password}" th:field="*{password}"
               name="password" id="password"/>
        <button type="submit" th:text="#{messages.form.signup}"></button>
    </form>
</div>
```

However I'd like to reuse this form as fragment from other views, but I can't do that because the `${userCredentials}` form object is not initialized. Can I somehow construct this object inside of my view like this?

```
<div th:if="${userCredentials == null}" th:with="userCredentials=new UserCredentials()"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to create an object using `new`, you can however create a static method on UserCredentials that returns a new object and use that.  Something like this:

```
public class UserCredentials {
  public static UserCredentials create() {
    return new UserCredentials();
  }
}
```

and in the thymeleaf

```
<div th:if="${userCredentials == null}" th:with="userCredentials=${T(your.package.here.UserCredentials).create()}"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object in `th:with` by using

```
th:with="userCredentials=${new UserCredentials()}"
```